# How to test the IO throughput in SAS DATA Step?

Tags: performance, optimization, sas, performance-testing

I want to test if the system option `bufno` and `bufsize` can improve the data set effective.

Here is the test code:

```
    options bufno=1  bufsize=16k;
    %atstart;
    data target.dds_dep_pagesize16k;
        set tune.dds_dep_pagesize16k(obs=2000000);
    run;
    %atend;

    options bufno=100  bufsize=32k;
    %atstart;
    data target.dds_dep_pagesize16k;
        set tune.dds_dep_pagesize16k(obs=2000000);
    run;
    %atend;
    ...
    ...
```

`%atstart` and `%atend` are used to compute the run time of program between them.

If the size of data set is about 800 Mb then the change of `bufno` and `bufsize` has little effect on the run time.

However many papers said `bufno` and `bufsize` can optimize the program. Perhaps because I am running all the code within the same SAS session I am not measuring accurately. My question is : **should I test each code run time in a separate session and do I need choose a bigger data set?**

Comment: Needing to use a bigger data set depends entirely on the size of data set you will be processing in your production environment.

Answer (score 4):

BUFSIZE will generally only improve performance when increased if the dataset is very large, and by very large I mean has a lot of data in one row in addition to having many rows.  What it does is determines how much data is read with each pass; if you have 80 byte rows, a bufsize of 4096 even will read plenty of observations, after all.  If you have on the other hand 2056 byte rows, then a 4096 page will contain only one observation; so you have to read a new page for each observation, which is slow.

BUFNO is of no value whatsoever unless you are using SGIO, which from what I recall is generally not recommended.

In specific answer to the final question: There is no need to start a new SAS session for these options.  BUFSIZE may have some additional benefit if you have a larger dataset.

I would, in general, recommend looking more to your code rather than system options to optimize your runs.  As long as you're using a large memory space (as much as feasible on your machine, at least a couple GB), you are probably not going to gain too much from mucking about with system options.  If you can eliminate a few data passes instead, you will gain a lot more.

The one exception to this is SORTSIZE - set it to 1/3 of your MEMSIZE.  If you have 2GB MEMSIZE, then SORTSIZE should be 667M.  This determines how big of a dataset you can sort in memory, and is for some reason often very small.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do I have other method to improve the IO throughput, and enhance the use of memsize, because through windows task manager I find that SAS program always use memory size of less than 100M. Should the MEMSIZE be equal to total available memory size?Now my computer has 32G memory.

Comment: MEMSIZE should be less than 32G for sure since you don't want to use ALL memory or Windows will crash.  SAS does not use a ton of memory in normal operation; but that doesn't stop it from using more when it needs it (up to MEMSIZE).  So if it's hanging out at 100MB but needs to sort a 2GB dataset, and your MEMSIZE is 24GB and your SORTSIZE is 8GB, it will expand up to 6GB as it sorts the dataset.

Comment: Also BUFSIZE only affects the writes, not reads from an existing dataset tune.dds_dep_pagesize16k, whose BUFSIZE was fixed at its creation. And for this whole test the data is probably in the filesystem cache, so the size of I/Os has little effect. Testing with datasets larger than total RAM available will show different results.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about any serious data processing activity, I assume this always takes place on some disk array - which can be many things but at least it means there are several disks in some RAID format.
So to optimize SAS I/O performance all the way down to disks, you have to take the storage technology into consideration.

Here the BUFSIZE option comes useful in order to align application I/O pattern with the characteristics of the storage.
Most common situation is using RAID10 or RAID5 formats, where data is spread across disks in chunks of certain size - it's good to have the BUFSIZE aligned (1:1 or multiple of) with this block size - or stripe size. You should consult you storage admin about this size - it'll ne something like 64kB and its multiples.

With parity RAID format like RAID5, the data is spread across disks plus parity is calculated, so its good to always write data in such chunks so that all disks get the update and parity for them is calculated at once (no partial updates).

So for simplicity, for parity disk you can set BUFSIZE to stripe size multiplied by (number of disks in array minus 1). Alternatively, you can try to combine it with BUFNO to achieve the multiple.

Very good document regarding SAS I/O:[Best Practices for Configuring your IO Subsystem for SAS 9 Applications](http://support.sas.com/rnd/papers/sgf07/sgf2007-iosubsystem.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe SAS will report on disk I/O usage.  Assuming you're running in Windows you would have to use a program such as Performance Monitor (Start->Run->Type in 'perfmon') or for a simple visual you could use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795535) (which is like task manager but shows disk/network IO etc in more detail).

IMO the easiest ways to minimize I/O are (in order of effort to reward):

1. use compression
2. (as Joe suggests) minimize the number of times your program parses through the data (consider using views for interim steps if multiple steps are necessary)
3. make sure that your variables are not longer than they need to be. Drop any unnecessary variables.

Comment: Thanks. I have set the compress option. Then I find one page can contain more observations even if obslen is very long relative to it's BUFSIZE.